# Yii2 Change id in URL

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

Is it possible to change id in URL in Yii2 basic to something else my URL actual is

```
http://localhost:8585/yii40/wfp/web/post/view?id=368
```

I want to change it to

```
http://localhost:8585/yii40/wfp/web/post/view?post=368
```

My View is

```
 public function actionView($id)
        {
            return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: // /index.php?r=post%2Fedit&id=100   assume the alias "@postEdit" is defined as "post/edit"
echo Url::toRoute(['@postEdit', 'post' => 100]);  Please check 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html

Comment: where can I create that code Url::toRoute(['@postEdit', 'post' => 100])

Comment: add the view that you are using and the `actionView()` for `PostController`.

Comment: Thank you, so much

Comment: you have added the controller action, but havent added the file where you have the link that lands on this action kindly add that view file code too so that we can see if there is an anchor link or a gridview

Comment: I still having Undefined variable

Comment: did you updated your action, i have pointed it out in my answer **change the `actionView($id)` in your `PostController` to the `actionView($post)` and replace all occourences of the `$id` with `$post` inside the action code**

Comment: do select the answer if it helped you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to the link which on clicking lands on this action it could either be

- inside your `GridView`, **`/your_project_root/views/post/index.php`** file from where you are clicking to view the post detail by submitting the id.
- Or a normal link in your view somewhere

**1)** For GridView go to your action column and change the `['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn']` to the following

```
[ 'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn' ,
    'header' => 'Actions' ,
    'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}',
    'buttons'=>[
        'view'=>function($url,$model){
        $html = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>';
        return Html::a($html,["post/view",'post'=>$model->id]);
        }
    ],
] ,
```

and change the `actionView($id)` in your `PostController` to the `actionView($post)` and replace all occourences of the `$id` with `$post` inside the action code.

**2)** if it is a normal link then you have to just change the `url` for that link like below

```
Html::a($html,["post/view",'post'=>$model->id]);
```

where `$model` should be replaced by the appropriate variable.

Comment: It's not working, I I'm trying to change just id= in url to post=;

Comment: you have to  change the `actionView` too along with the anchor link

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you only want to change the name of `GET` parameter (id->post).

Assuming you have default app config, you need to find the view method (called actionView) in appropriate controller (PostController.php).

The method either takes $id parameter as its argument (like `public function actionView($id)`) or retrieves 'id' from $_GET superglobal array later (like `$modelId = $_GET['id'];` or `$modelId = Yii::$app->request->get('id');`)

This is the place where you change it.

To get a better idea of Yii2 app structure and ways to handle requests please see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html#application-structure

Comment: I don't yet find out how

Comment: Change $id to $post in 2 places in your view method. Then http://localhost:8585/yii40/wfp/web/post/view?post=368 should become accessible.